# JQuery UI Resizable

Tags: jquery-ui-resizable

I am using JQuery UI to re-size a div vertically only (dragging from the bottom edge. I set the div **height:200px** and **overflow:auto**.

The JQuery looks like this:

```
$("#resizable").resizable({handles: 's',ghost: false,animate: false,});
$("#resizable" ).resizable({ maxHeight: 300 });
```

The re-size function works great while the div is empty or has content but no overflow. if however there is an overflow, the drag handle moves out of place up (from the bottom) as I move the scroll bar down. It does not stay on the bottom edge which drives me crazy because it makes it unusable.

I can not figure out how to fix this. Could some one please help out?

Thank you!

HTML:

```
<div id="resizable" class="divTop">
  <div class="dataView">
    <?php require_once(ROOT_PATH.'user/controls/data/get_data.php'); ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try putting a the content inside another div which is(for example) 90% of the resizable div?

jQuery methods modify the HTML, they aren't magic. Look at the new HTML in Firebug and find ways to work around it.

Comment: This is weird, it always worked for me. Could you upload a quick example?